# How to change: values in an array and save states of a function in a MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am currently working on a GUI to model the effects of low temperature on a PV array. The GUI (as made from the GUIDE) as of now takes in user inputs from text boxes in order to change some of the parameters of the PV modules (such as short circuit current and ideality factor).

The GUI will use a function I have written for calculating current (I) and voltage (V) and generate an IV curve depending on whatever parameters the user inputs.

However, I want to the GUI to be able to first generate a general IV curve from a set of parameters that user inputs (which is what the GUI can do as of now). After this, I would like to user to select a cell or row of cells in the array, change the parameters for that single cell, and view its effect on the IV curve of the entire array. So the user would input cell(1,2) or cell(1:3,2) and be able to change the params for those cells only.

How would I be able to run the function multiple times and save the results from each change?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code(for vectors):

```
headers ={'data1'  'data2'  'data3'  'data4' 'data5' 'data6'};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
def = round(rand(1,6)*20);
def = def';
def = num2str(def);
deff = cellstr(def);
answer = inputdlg(headers, dlg_title, num_lines, deff);
```

do not forget:
|God is bigger|